# Render a hexcolor inline in an R markdown file

Tags: r, colors, hex, r-markdown, rendering

I am writing an R markdown document and would like to render a hex color swatch inline as a small colored square. To give an example output, Slack does the following when you post a hexcode.

[image]

I would expect it to be something similar to:

`` `r #72B4DA` ``

My search has only returned results on how to change the color of chart plots or other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but you can use plain html.

```
<div class="container">
<div>#72B4DA</div>
<div><p style="width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid #000;margin-left:3px; background-color:#72B4DA;"></p></div>
</div>
<style>.container {
  display: flex;
}
</style>
```

Hope it helps you.